# mod_rewrite one url string

Tags: mod-rewrite

Can somebody tell me how to get mod_rewrite to rename this:

```
our-work-section.php?id=3&title=something
to
our-work-section/something/3
```

Right now my .htaccess is in directory **C:\workspace\www\brown**, My vhost is setup for **http://workspace/**, So I did a RewriteBase below. I currently Have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www/brown/
RewriteRule ^/our-work-section/?$    our-work-section.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

My error log isn't saying anything, and the page doesn't do anything. I've tried toggling slashes / here and there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(our-work-section)/?$ /our-work-section.php?id=$1 [L]
```

**EDIT**

This one will work. I tested it

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(our-work-section)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /our-work-section.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That does not do anything -- Im baffled! I tried this on the live server and locally.